# Connect to MS Sql 2008 on local VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, virtual-machines

I have a test machine.

Server 2008 with Hyper V

MSSQL 2008 Enterprise

Lets call it MACHINE A

on the VM
it is as well Server 2008 with another MSSQL 2008 Ent

Call it VM B

I setup a DB on MACHINE A then backed it up and restored following the prepare database for mirroring instructions on MSDN onto VM B.

I used to be able to connect to the VM B Instance from the main test server (MACHINE A) but now I cannot for some reason.
It cannot seem to find the instance at all even when I browse network databases.
I can ping the VM from any computer on the network and access its shares so I know it is discoverable.

Just the end of a long day maybe I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Firewall?

Comment: LOL I wish it was that simple....

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

VM said firewall was off but when i clicked "allow programs through firewall" in the Firewall control panel it showed on!
Turned it off and worked right away.

Comment: And I didn't get marked the right answer because?

Comment: Because I got distracted by end users and there made up Quickbooks problems. HEHE. Marked it now.

Comment: same here with fantasy Word macro issues...